# Build the Azure IoT sdk on edison

Tags: azure, iot, intel-edison

I am trying to run a C sample on Intel Edison like in :

https://github.com/neeraj-khanna/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/doc/run_sample_on_intel_edison.md

I am trying to Build the Azure IoT sdk ,
I Set necessary environment variables

```
export CFLAGS="-I/home/root/qpid-proton/proton-c/include"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/root/qpid-proton/proton-c/include"

export LDFLAGS="-L/lib/"
```

and try to run ./build.sh in azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/Linux
but I am getting a error :

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "azure-c-shared-utility/c" which is not an
  existing directory.
```

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: azure-c-shared-utility is a separate GitHub project. Have you tried:    git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility.git In your "azure-iot-sdks/c" directory?

Comment: I've tested my answer above on raspbian on a Raspberry PI 2. It works...

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for the Intel Edison running Yocto have been updated.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/yocto-intel-edison-c.md
Have you used the --recursive option when cloning the SDK repo?
This is now necessary as the SDK is using sub module to use other libs sitting on other repos.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The --recursive option isn't supported on the git client that is default on Edison.

There are 3 options:

1. Manually clone all of the submodules.  This is error prone, especially if submodules update or change.
2. Clone onto a different system and use your favorite transfer program to get it onto the Edison.
3. Build your own private git client on Edison and use that one instead.

I personally use the BitVise ssh client on my Windows machine to transfer my Windows clone to my Edison.  I do all of my file editing on my Windows machine and I use https://github.com/avranju/rsync to keep the Windows machine and the Edison in sync.  It's not a perfect workflow, but it works for me, especially when I use the Visual Studio GDB extension to debug (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/18/announcing-the-vs-gdb-debugger-extension/)